# ¿cómo asignar texto dinamicamente desde activity?

Tags: android, botón, textview, edittext

tengo 4 elementos que deseo asignarles texto dinamicamente desde mi activity estos son:

1 y 2  para el caso de estos dos editText deseo manipular el atributo hint

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtuser"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint=""
    android:inputType="text"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtpasswd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint=""
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    />
```

3 y 4  Para esto dos elementos deseo manipular el atributo text

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnlogin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/register"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="25sp"
    />
```

en mi activity.java intenté esto pero aún no me ha funcionado:

```
   if (language=="en")
    {

        register.setText("Register");
        btnlogin.setText("Log in");
        txt_user.setHint("User");
        txt_passwd.setHint("Password");



    }//fin de if

    else if (language=="es")
    {
        register.setText("Registrar");
        btnlogin.setText("Ingresar");
        txt_user.setHint("Usuario");
        txt_passwd.setHint("Contraseña");

    }
```

De antemano gracias por su valioso tiempo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, no entiendo muy bien tu pregunta. Deberías nutrirlo más.

Pero por lo que entiendo lo que deseas es cambiar el idioma de tu aplicación. Android tiene las herramientas para eso. Y es muy facil de implementar.

Lo que debes hacer es ir al directorio String del proyecto y crear nuevo xml

```
MyProject/
    res/
       values/
           strings.xml
       values-es/
           strings.xml
       values-fr/
           strings.xml
```

Para el caso de inglés

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">My Application</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello World!</string>
</resources>
```

Español

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">Mi Aplicación</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hola Mundo!</string>
</resources>
```

Observa bien que se identifican igual pero en cada caso hace uso de el idioma que le corresponde.

Debes asegurarte que los dos archivos tengan el mismo nombre pero en diferente idioma. Eso se cambia cuando se crea uno nuevo.

Para poder utilizarlos en tus layout deberías escribirlo referenciando a ese xml con el id con que lo has identificado

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

Hacer eso cambiará el idioma según sea la configuración de tu teléfono.
Para más información visita 
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Saludos...

Comment: gracias @Angel Manual Elias, intentaré lo que dices

Comment: Angel Manuel Elias, mil gracias hermano esa fue la solución, saludos!